# Python3: ValueError: I/O operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

I just want to make the `print` output redirect to a file. my code as below:

```
import sys

# define the log file that receives your log info
log_file = open("message.log", "w")
# redirect print output to log file
sys.stdout = log_file

print ("Now all print info will be written to message.log")
# any command line that you will execute
...

log_file.close()

print ("Now this will be presented on screen")
```

After execute the script, it comes an error:

```
[~/Liaohaifeng]$ python3 log.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log.py", line 14, in <module>
  print ("Now this will be presented on screen")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

why does this happen? if I update my script as below:

```
import sys

# make a copy of original stdout route
stdout_backup = sys.stdout
# define the log file that receives your log info
log_file = open("message.log", "w")
# redirect print output to log file
sys.stdout = log_file

print ("Now all print info will be written to message.log"
# any command line that you will execute
...

log_file.close()
# restore the output to initial pattern
sys.stdout = stdout_backup

print ("Now this will be presented on screen")
```

It will be OK. So, could you please kindly tell me the theory in this issue?

Comment: What would you expect for the first example? You seemed to know how `print` works. `print` by default, always print to `sys.stdout`. If you closed `sys.stdout`, where should `print` print to? It will not magically resets itself back to the original `stdout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `print` does not print to a closed filehandle and you have closed `sys.stdout`, potentially breaking any prints evoked after it closed. Which may happen even without your knowledge, eg somewhere in the imported code. That's why you shouldn't fiddle with `sys.*` variables (or any variables you didn't create, really) unless you absolutely need to. There is a proper way to redirect `print` output to a file and it goes like this:

```
log_file = open('message.log', 'w')
print('Stuff to print in the log', file=log_file)
log_file.close()
```

Or even safer like this:

```
with open('message.log', 'w') as log_file:
    # Do stuff
    print('Stuff to print in the log', file=log_file)
```

The handle will automatically flush and close when the `with` block finishes.